# Using a non-used "fan" switch for new lights in a bedroom where fan & light are controlled by one switch vs. 2

Tags: lighting, switch, fans

It is increasingly hard to get an electrician to come out for small jobs and is expensive as well. I know I can do this wiring myself, I just need some guidance.

In our bedroom, we need more light. The fan/light is on one switch (left switch in photo) and works via remote. I want to use the unused, but wired in, "fan switch" (middle switch in photo) that does nothing now for some new LED can lights. The switch on the far right works an LED track light in the tray ceiling. I was hoping to simply be able to tap the existing wiring in the attic to that middle unused switch and have it for the lights. Where I am uncertain is how to do that as I cannot determine which wire that is and if it is that simple. Otherwise my thought is I have to either open a hole in the wall to access the switch box or cut a hole in the switch box top and try to fish into that hole from above in the attic down the wall and then connect a new wire to the switch to access it for the new lights. The switch already has power, so that should work; but not sure how easy it will be without accessing a hole above the switchbox in the drywall. I have pictures and video I can post or email if you email me. Thanks for the help.

[image: Switches]

Comment: Very hard to tell from the picture, so please manually trace the wires and confirm/deny: (a) Red wire from left (functioning remote fan/light) + *one* of the black wires from the middle switch go to the same cable along with a white wire from the bundle of whites; (b) the black wire from the left switch plus the other black wire from the middle switch join up in wire nut with at least one other black wire.

Answer (score 2):

Walking this back to the beginning...there was a fan/light combo using the left and middle switches.  At some point the fan was swaped out out or rewired to be completely on the left switch.  What would have happened to the now unwanted wires from the middle switch?  Easy and proper solution is they capped them in place in the J-box the fixture is mounted to.  Anything else would have been 100x the work for no benefit.  Drop your fan and check for them.

If the wires are there, that is good news because you can uncap and splice right there in the J-box and run the wire to the new LED installation.